Not able to plot embedding diagram of wormhole

I'm trying to reproduce the embedding diagram of the wormhole given in Fig. 3 and Fig. 4 in the article https://arxiv.org/pdf/2407.05111. I'm having trouble numerically integrating and reproducing the plots. I have used the shape function (b(r)) for Gaussian distribution given in Equation (14) and the equation shown in Eq. (25) to plot the embedding diagram around the "z-axis" first. I have used the following code for reproducing Fig. 3:
c0 = 0.05;
m2c2 = -0.05;
m2c1 = -0.3;
M = 1.8;
\[Theta] = 0.02;
e = -1.05;

b[r_] = -c0^2 m2c2 r - 1/2 c0 m2c1 r^2 - e - (
   2 E^(-(r^2/(4 \[Theta]))) M r)/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Sqrt[\[Theta]]) + 
   2 M Erf[r/(2 Sqrt[\[Theta]])];

z[x_] := NIntegrate[Sqrt[r/(r - b[r]) - 1], {r, 4.825, x}]; (*throat radius = 4.825*)

Plot[z[x], {x, 4.825,10}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]

However, I'm only getting a blank canvas as output.
Also for reproducing Fig. 4, I'm using the code:
RevolutionPlot3D[z[x], {x,4.825, 50}, RevolutionAxis -> "Z", 
 SphericalRegion -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]

I'm getting errors as NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. and NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in r near {r} = {4.82523}. NIntegrate obtained 0.247298 +0.0712356 I and 0.00545442830264895 for the integral and error estimates..
Thanks.

The function z returns complex numbers, which can't be plotted using Plot.
z[x_] := 
  NIntegrate[Sqrt[r/(r - b[r]) - 1], {r, 4.825, x}, MaxRecursion -> 100];

Plotting (+/-) real parts results in something that looks a bit like Fig 3:
Plot[{Re@z[x], -Re@z[x]}, {x, 4.825, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, All}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]


Here is the revolution (very slow; used reduced PlotPoints to make it faster):
Show[
 RevolutionPlot3D[Re@z[x], {x, 4.825, 10}, RevolutionAxis -> "Z", 
  PlotPoints -> 2],
 RevolutionPlot3D[-Re@z[x], {x, 4.825, 10}, RevolutionAxis -> "Z", 
  PlotPoints -> 2]]


Update
I couldn't easily figure out how to improve the plot directly, but here is a workaround using sampled points from the Re@z[x] curve:
pts = MeshCoordinates[DiscretizeGraphics[Plot[Re@z[x], {x, 4.825, 10}]]];
f = Interpolation[pts];
RevolutionPlot3D[{{x, f[x]}, {x, -f[x]}}, {x, 4.825, 10}, PlotStyle -> Yellow]



Thanks a lot. @MelaGo

Is there any way to remove those dark ring-like patches in the 3D plot?

@BibhashDas Please see update to the answer

Thank you. @MelaGo
